# Sum of squares of eigen values of adjacency matrix is equal to twice the number of edges

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges. Let $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ldots \ge \lambda_n$ be the eigen values of $A$ .

Show that :

> $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2=2e$

**My try**: Applying induction on $n$ . Checking for $n=2$;
$\sum_{i=1}^2 \lambda_i^2=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2-2\lambda_1\lambda_2$

Since trace of adjacency matrix is zero so $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)=0$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-e$ since sum of all $2\times 2$ principal minors is equal to $-e$

How to proceed after this ?Please help.

Comment: You could maybe write down the definition of adjacency matrix in case people have forgotten it. Also is the graph directed or undirected?

Comment: A hint could be to try and use $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^k = Tr(A^k)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of an adjacency matrix $A$, it follows that $[A^2]_{ii}$ is equal to the number of edges connected to $i$, i.e. the degree of $i$: $d_i$. Now recall (or easily rederive) that $\sum_i d_i=2e$. Finally use the fact that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_i^2$ along with the fact that their sum is equal to the trace of $A^2$.

Comment: thank you very much ,i got it